# mysql sum() does not give correct decimal value

Tags: mysql, sum, decimal

I have 9 entries in a varchar column all at 2 decimal places. When i go to add them with sum() rather than the right answer it gives me at multiple decimal places off by a tiny bit. Why would this happen?

```
Select sum(atotal) AS itemstotal FROM mytable
```

This ill give me 248.299999999998 or something like that rather then the 248.3 that i calculate when adding my items

Comment: Select FORMAT(sum(atotal),2) AS itemstotal FROM mytable

Comment: Please post those 9 "numbers".

Comment: 6.00, 6.00, 56.00, 118.00, 6.00, 15.00, 2.20, 24.10, 15.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select cast(sum(atotal) as decimal(12,2)) AS itemstotal FROM mytable
```

Comment: Yes. my mistake was the column was left as varchar(45). I changed it to decimal(13,2) and it works fine now